# I'm installing an app where I have to give my app_code write permissions. EDIT: Error MSG included

Tags: iis, iis-7, permissions, blogengine.net, windows-server-2012

I'm developing a site on a shared hosting company (asp.net/c#).  I'm on a Windows 2012 server.  I'm using IIS7.  I'm trying to install blogengine.net, which requires the app_code folder to have write permissions.

I can find nowhere in my control panel where it lets me grant write permissions anywhere.

Likewise, I see no option for this in IIS7.

Can anybody offer me guidance on how to grant write permissions to the app_code folder if I'm with a shared hosting company?  Thanks!

Here's what my shared hosting control panel looks like.  But I thought there would be a way to grant write permissions via IIS7:

[image: Control Panel]

**EDIT:**

Here's my specific error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is   
temporarily unavailable.
Most likely causes:

The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:

Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which 
module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for 
failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://domain.org:80/blog/account/login
Physical Path      E:\web\controlpanelusername\htdocs\blog\account\login
Logon Method       BlogEngine.NET Custom Identity
Logon User     Anonymous
```

I just got an answer back from the hosting company and here's what they said:

"*Your IIS and aspnet users are granted full set of permissions on your site root and all subsequent directories by default. Your and your web applications should be able to write to any directory. The permissions of those users cannot be altered, and that's why they are not listed in permissions manager. Permission manager is for additional users that you create in User/Quota Manager only.* "

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has a similar issue, this may be a solution:

I had an IIS7 rewrite rule that was removing .aspx extensions.  So if I went to domain.org/about.aspx, it would rewrite to domain.org/about

This was messing up the application I was trying to install.  Removing this rewrite rule solved my issue.